# conjugate closure of a subgroup

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Let $G$ be a group with subgroups $H$ and $K$. Define $H^K = \langle aHa^-1 \; |\; a\in K \rangle$ as the conjugate closure of $H$ in $K$. Then $H^K = H$ $\implies$ $HK = KH$.

Let $x\in HK$ then $x=hb$ for some $h\in H$ and $b\in K$. Then $h\in H^K$ so that $h = (a_1h_1a_1^{-1})(a_2h_2a_1^{-2})\ldots (a_nh_na_n^{-1})$ where $a_i \in K$ and $h_i \in H$ for $i= 1,\ldots,n$. Now we can express each of the $a_i$ as $a_i = bc_i$ where $c_i \in K$. Therefore, $$h = (bc_1h_1c_1^{-1}b^{-1})(bc_2h_2c_1^{-1}b^{-1})\ldots (bc_nh_nc_n^{-1}b^{-1}) = b(c_1h_1c_1^{-1})(c_2h_2c_1^{-1})\ldots (c_nh_nc_n^{-1})b^{-1}$$ Mulitplying by $b$ to the left gives, $x= hb= b(c_1h_1c_1^{-1})(c_2h_2c_1^{-1})\ldots (c_nh_nc_n^{-1}) \in KH$ since $(c_1h_1c_1^{-1})(c_2h_2c_1^{-1})\ldots (c_nh_nc_n^{-1}) \in H^K = H$. The other inclusion follows similarly.

I want to also show that $HK = KH$ $\implies$ $H^K = H$, but I'm not sure if this is true in general. Clearly $H \leq H^K$. If I can show that $aHa^{-1}\leq H$ for all $a\in K$, I would be done. I can't seem to show this

Comment: Under this condition $HK=KH$ is a group and both $H$ and $H^K$ are subgroups of $HK$. In fact, $H^K$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $HK$ containing $H$. Then it is EQUIVALENT to show that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $HK$.I arrive at here now. But I feel that it is not necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your hint. So I need to show that $H \unlhd HK$ then that would imply $H^K = H$?

Comment: Exactly. But it is not always true.

Answer (score 1):

Followed with my hint above. Consider $G=S_3$. Let $H$ be $<(12)>$ and $K$ be $<(123)>$. Then $HK=KH=S_3$. But $H$ is not a normal subgroup.